# Problema conexion pdo PHP

Tags: php, postgresql

Tengo un pequeño proglema, me sale el siguiente error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function execute()

```
<?php 


$conn = new PDO("pgsql:dbname=fhernandez;host=localhost","postgres","monotono11");

$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM region");
$stmt = execute();
$resultados = $stmt->get_result();

echo '<pre>';
var_dump($resultados->fetch_assoc());
echo '</pre>';  



?>
```

Comment: Esto `$stmt = execute();` debe ir así `$stmt->execute();`

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con esto

```
<?php 
$options = [
    \PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    \PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => \PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
    \PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false,
];
$pdo = new \PDO(
    'mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=fhernandez;charset=utf8',
    'postgres',
    'monotono11',
    $options
);

$stmt = $pdo->query('SELECT * FROM region');
$resultado= $stmt->fetchAll();

echo $resultado;
 ?>
```

Comment: El op usa postgresql para conectarse y no mysql

Comment: funciono, pero eliminando el tipo de conexion pdo , use el de mi codigo, muchas gracias